# XML & .NET - Sort only elements in the deepest nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I bumped into this challenge where I hit a wall and can't progress without some additional knowledge:

I have this structure:

[image: UI Structure]

And I want to sort only the elements in the deepest node. The amount and the names of the upper nodes vary quite a bit.

My problem is that very node starts with the name **<CompTool**, so I'm lost about how to sort only the latest ones because if I sort using the name **<CompTool** I'll sort every folder and element in upper nodes.

[image: XML Nodes]

This is the XML code for the examples above:

```
<!--xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"-->
<ToolsItemsManager Version="4" Istoolkit="1" Machine="">
    <Components>
        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="1" Name="Cutters" Type="6" FolderOf="1" Description="">
            <Components>
                <CompTool Ver="2" ID="5" ExtrId="12181715949" Name="SubNode 1" Type="6" FolderOf="1" Description="">
                    <Components>
                        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="6" ExtrId="121817151010" Name="SubNode 2" Type="6" FolderOf="1" Description="">
                            <Components>
                                <CompTool Ver="2" ID="7" ExtrId="121817151015" Name="SubNode 3" Type="6" FolderOf="1" Description="">
                                    <Components>
                                        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="8" ExtrId="121817151020" Name="SubNode 4" Type="6" FolderOf="1" Description="">
                                            <Components>
                                                <CompTool Ver="2" ID="9" ExtrId="121817151044" Name="SubNode 5" Type="6" FolderOf="1" Description="">
                                                    <Components>
                                                        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="10" ExtrId="121817151049" Name="SubNode 6" Type="6" FolderOf="1" Description="">
                                                            <Components>
                                                                <CompTool Ver="1" ID="11" ExtrId="121817151113" Name="2222" CatalogNum="" Description="" Hyperlink="" HasCoolantHole="0" Price="0" Mass="0" Quantity="1" MinQuantity="1" Type="1" ShapeType="0" IsMilling="-1" ToolType="2" InsertOnly="-1">
                                                                    <Mounting ConnectToJoint="">
                                                                        <MountingX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                        <MountingPos x="0" y="0" z="45"/>
                                                                        <MountingAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                    </Mounting>
                                                                    <Shape Ver="4" InchMode="0" Name="" ShapeType="0" NumFlutes="2" Rough="0" IsInputSA="-1">
                                                                        <LenParams>
                                                                            <AD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <CL Units="0" Val="24"/>
                                                                            <D Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SL Units="0" Val="30"/>
                                                                            <TL Units="0" Val="80"/>
                                                                        </LenParams>
                                                                        <Params>
                                                                            <HelicalAngle Units="0" Val="45"/>
                                                                            <SA Units="0" Val="0"/>
                                                                        </Params>
                                                                    </Shape>
                                                                    <Joints>
                                                                        <Joint Ver="2" InchMode="0" Name="Joint_1" ForPartMounting="0" DriveUnitType="3">
                                                                            <PlugIn>
                                                                                <PlugInX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                                <PlugInPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                            </PlugIn>
                                                                            <Filter Ver="1"/>
                                                                        </Joint>
                                                                    </Joints>
                                                                    <CuttingConditionsList Default="1">
                                                                        <CC Ver="1" InchMode="0" Precision="3" Name="Default" Id="1" OperationType="4" WorkMaterial="" Comment="">
                                                                            <MillingFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="2" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.1" Z="0.01" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="200" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="70" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="70" Normal="0" Limit="0" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </MillingFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurningFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="4" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.05" Z="0" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="100" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="0" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="90" Normal="70" Limit="1000" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </TurningFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurretCoolant Ver="1" Device="2" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                            <MachineCoolant Ver="1" Device="0" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                        </CC>
                                                                    </CuttingConditionsList>
                                                                    <Material Ver="1" Material="0" PercentMaterial="100" CheckPercent="0"/>
                                                                    <CutPoints>
                                                                        <CutPoint Ver="5" InchMode="0" Name="Cutting point" Id="1" OperationType="0" RadIndx="0" Description="" Hyperlink="" Color="62207" ForCut="-1" LinkToDiamCutter="-1" LockH="-1" CuttingCondition="1" OffsetNum="1" OffsetIndex="1" Radius="3" OriginNum="0" AutoOriginNum="-1" MeasureOrien="0" Flip="0" DTAxisVal="0" NosePointX="0" NosePointY="0" NosePointZ="0" CheckToolBreakage="0" CheckToolLength="0" CheckToolRadius="0" LengthTolerance="0.5" RadiusTolerance="0.1" UsedInHR="0" UsedInPart="0"/>
                                                                    </CutPoints>
                                                                </CompTool>
                                                                <CompTool Ver="1" ID="12" ExtrId="121817151124" Name="1111" CatalogNum="" Description="" Hyperlink="" HasCoolantHole="0" Price="0" Mass="0" Quantity="1" MinQuantity="1" Type="1" ShapeType="0" IsMilling="-1" ToolType="2" InsertOnly="-1">
                                                                    <Mounting ConnectToJoint="">
                                                                        <MountingX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                        <MountingPos x="0" y="0" z="45"/>
                                                                        <MountingAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                    </Mounting>
                                                                    <Shape Ver="4" InchMode="0" Name="" ShapeType="0" NumFlutes="2" Rough="0" IsInputSA="-1">
                                                                        <LenParams>
                                                                            <AD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <CL Units="0" Val="24"/>
                                                                            <D Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SL Units="0" Val="30"/>
                                                                            <TL Units="0" Val="80"/>
                                                                        </LenParams>
                                                                        <Params>
                                                                            <HelicalAngle Units="0" Val="45"/>
                                                                            <SA Units="0" Val="0"/>
                                                                        </Params>
                                                                    </Shape>
                                                                    <Joints>
                                                                        <Joint Ver="2" InchMode="0" Name="Joint_1" ForPartMounting="0" DriveUnitType="3">
                                                                            <PlugIn>
                                                                                <PlugInX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                                <PlugInPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                            </PlugIn>
                                                                            <Filter Ver="1"/>
                                                                        </Joint>
                                                                    </Joints>
                                                                    <CuttingConditionsList Default="1">
                                                                        <CC Ver="1" InchMode="0" Precision="3" Name="Default" Id="1" OperationType="4" WorkMaterial="" Comment="">
                                                                            <MillingFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="2" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.1" Z="0.01" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="200" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="70" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="70" Normal="0" Limit="0" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </MillingFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurningFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="4" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.05" Z="0" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="100" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="0" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="90" Normal="70" Limit="1000" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </TurningFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurretCoolant Ver="1" Device="2" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                            <MachineCoolant Ver="1" Device="0" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                        </CC>
                                                                    </CuttingConditionsList>
                                                                    <Material Ver="1" Material="0" PercentMaterial="100" CheckPercent="0"/>
                                                                    <CutPoints>
                                                                        <CutPoint Ver="5" InchMode="0" Name="Cutting point" Id="1" OperationType="0" RadIndx="0" Description="" Hyperlink="" Color="62207" ForCut="-1" LinkToDiamCutter="-1" LockH="-1" CuttingCondition="1" OffsetNum="1" OffsetIndex="1" Radius="3" OriginNum="0" AutoOriginNum="-1" MeasureOrien="0" Flip="0" DTAxisVal="0" NosePointX="0" NosePointY="0" NosePointZ="0" CheckToolBreakage="0" CheckToolLength="0" CheckToolRadius="0" LengthTolerance="0.5" RadiusTolerance="0.1" UsedInHR="0" UsedInPart="0"/>
                                                                    </CutPoints>
                                                                </CompTool>
                                                                <CompTool Ver="1" ID="13" ExtrId="121817151133" Name="5555" CatalogNum="" Description="" Hyperlink="" HasCoolantHole="0" Price="0" Mass="0" Quantity="1" MinQuantity="1" Type="1" ShapeType="0" IsMilling="-1" ToolType="2" InsertOnly="-1">
                                                                    <Mounting ConnectToJoint="">
                                                                        <MountingX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                        <MountingPos x="0" y="0" z="45"/>
                                                                        <MountingAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                    </Mounting>
                                                                    <Shape Ver="4" InchMode="0" Name="" ShapeType="0" NumFlutes="2" Rough="0" IsInputSA="-1">
                                                                        <LenParams>
                                                                            <AD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <CL Units="0" Val="24"/>
                                                                            <D Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SL Units="0" Val="30"/>
                                                                            <TL Units="0" Val="80"/>
                                                                        </LenParams>
                                                                        <Params>
                                                                            <HelicalAngle Units="0" Val="45"/>
                                                                            <SA Units="0" Val="0"/>
                                                                        </Params>
                                                                    </Shape>
                                                                    <Joints>
                                                                        <Joint Ver="2" InchMode="0" Name="Joint_1" ForPartMounting="0" DriveUnitType="3">
                                                                            <PlugIn>
                                                                                <PlugInX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                                <PlugInPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                            </PlugIn>
                                                                            <Filter Ver="1"/>
                                                                        </Joint>
                                                                    </Joints>
                                                                    <CuttingConditionsList Default="1">
                                                                        <CC Ver="1" InchMode="0" Precision="3" Name="Default" Id="1" OperationType="4" WorkMaterial="" Comment="">
                                                                            <MillingFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="2" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.1" Z="0.01" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="200" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="70" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="70" Normal="0" Limit="0" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </MillingFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurningFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="4" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.05" Z="0" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="100" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="0" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="90" Normal="70" Limit="1000" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </TurningFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurretCoolant Ver="1" Device="2" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                            <MachineCoolant Ver="1" Device="0" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                        </CC>
                                                                    </CuttingConditionsList>
                                                                    <Material Ver="1" Material="0" PercentMaterial="100" CheckPercent="0"/>
                                                                    <CutPoints>
                                                                        <CutPoint Ver="5" InchMode="0" Name="Cutting point" Id="1" OperationType="0" RadIndx="0" Description="" Hyperlink="" Color="62207" ForCut="-1" LinkToDiamCutter="-1" LockH="-1" CuttingCondition="1" OffsetNum="1" OffsetIndex="1" Radius="3" OriginNum="0" AutoOriginNum="-1" MeasureOrien="0" Flip="0" DTAxisVal="0" NosePointX="0" NosePointY="0" NosePointZ="0" CheckToolBreakage="0" CheckToolLength="0" CheckToolRadius="0" LengthTolerance="0.5" RadiusTolerance="0.1" UsedInHR="0" UsedInPart="0"/>
                                                                    </CutPoints>
                                                                </CompTool>
                                                                <CompTool Ver="1" ID="14" ExtrId="121817151144" Name="3333" CatalogNum="" Description="" Hyperlink="" HasCoolantHole="0" Price="0" Mass="0" Quantity="1" MinQuantity="1" Type="1" ShapeType="0" IsMilling="-1" ToolType="2" InsertOnly="-1">
                                                                    <Mounting ConnectToJoint="">
                                                                        <MountingX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                        <MountingPos x="0" y="0" z="45"/>
                                                                        <MountingAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                    </Mounting>
                                                                    <Shape Ver="4" InchMode="0" Name="" ShapeType="0" NumFlutes="2" Rough="0" IsInputSA="-1">
                                                                        <LenParams>
                                                                            <AD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <CL Units="0" Val="24"/>
                                                                            <D Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SL Units="0" Val="30"/>
                                                                            <TL Units="0" Val="80"/>
                                                                        </LenParams>
                                                                        <Params>
                                                                            <HelicalAngle Units="0" Val="45"/>
                                                                            <SA Units="0" Val="0"/>
                                                                        </Params>
                                                                    </Shape>
                                                                    <Joints>
                                                                        <Joint Ver="2" InchMode="0" Name="Joint_1" ForPartMounting="0" DriveUnitType="3">
                                                                            <PlugIn>
                                                                                <PlugInX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                                <PlugInPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                            </PlugIn>
                                                                            <Filter Ver="1"/>
                                                                        </Joint>
                                                                    </Joints>
                                                                    <CuttingConditionsList Default="1">
                                                                        <CC Ver="1" InchMode="0" Precision="3" Name="Default" Id="1" OperationType="4" WorkMaterial="" Comment="">
                                                                            <MillingFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="2" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.1" Z="0.01" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="200" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="70" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="70" Normal="0" Limit="0" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </MillingFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurningFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="4" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.05" Z="0" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="100" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="0" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="90" Normal="70" Limit="1000" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </TurningFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurretCoolant Ver="1" Device="2" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                            <MachineCoolant Ver="1" Device="0" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                        </CC>
                                                                    </CuttingConditionsList>
                                                                    <Material Ver="1" Material="0" PercentMaterial="100" CheckPercent="0"/>
                                                                    <CutPoints>
                                                                        <CutPoint Ver="5" InchMode="0" Name="Cutting point" Id="1" OperationType="0" RadIndx="0" Description="" Hyperlink="" Color="62207" ForCut="-1" LinkToDiamCutter="-1" LockH="-1" CuttingCondition="1" OffsetNum="1" OffsetIndex="1" Radius="3" OriginNum="0" AutoOriginNum="-1" MeasureOrien="0" Flip="0" DTAxisVal="0" NosePointX="0" NosePointY="0" NosePointZ="0" CheckToolBreakage="0" CheckToolLength="0" CheckToolRadius="0" LengthTolerance="0.5" RadiusTolerance="0.1" UsedInHR="0" UsedInPart="0"/>
                                                                    </CutPoints>
                                                                </CompTool>
                                                                <CompTool Ver="1" ID="15" ExtrId="121817151154" Name="2222" CatalogNum="" Description="" Hyperlink="" HasCoolantHole="0" Price="0" Mass="0" Quantity="1" MinQuantity="1" Type="1" ShapeType="0" IsMilling="-1" ToolType="2" InsertOnly="-1">
                                                                    <Mounting ConnectToJoint="">
                                                                        <MountingX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                        <MountingZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                        <MountingPos x="0" y="0" z="45"/>
                                                                        <MountingAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                    </Mounting>
                                                                    <Shape Ver="4" InchMode="0" Name="" ShapeType="0" NumFlutes="2" Rough="0" IsInputSA="-1">
                                                                        <LenParams>
                                                                            <AD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <CL Units="0" Val="24"/>
                                                                            <D Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SD Units="0" Val="6"/>
                                                                            <SL Units="0" Val="30"/>
                                                                            <TL Units="0" Val="80"/>
                                                                        </LenParams>
                                                                        <Params>
                                                                            <HelicalAngle Units="0" Val="45"/>
                                                                            <SA Units="0" Val="0"/>
                                                                        </Params>
                                                                    </Shape>
                                                                    <Joints>
                                                                        <Joint Ver="2" InchMode="0" Name="Joint_1" ForPartMounting="0" DriveUnitType="3">
                                                                            <PlugIn>
                                                                                <PlugInX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                                                <PlugInPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                                <PlugInAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                                            </PlugIn>
                                                                            <Filter Ver="1"/>
                                                                        </Joint>
                                                                    </Joints>
                                                                    <CuttingConditionsList Default="1">
                                                                        <CC Ver="1" InchMode="0" Precision="3" Name="Default" Id="1" OperationType="4" WorkMaterial="" Comment="">
                                                                            <MillingFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="2" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.1" Z="0.01" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="200" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="70" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="70" Normal="0" Limit="0" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </MillingFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurningFeedSpin Ver="1" InchMode="0" RiskLevel="5">
                                                                                <Feeds Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="4" Normal="0.1" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="0.05" Z="0" ZOnlyPenetration="0" Link="100" LeadIn="100" LeadOut="100"/>
                                                                                <Spins Ver="1" InchMode="0" Units="0" Rate="0" CheckFinish="-1" Finish="90" Normal="70" Limit="1000" Dir="0"/>
                                                                            </TurningFeedSpin>
                                                                            <TurretCoolant Ver="1" Device="2" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                            <MachineCoolant Ver="1" Device="0" Flood="0" FloodHP="0" FloodLP="0" FloodVal="0" Mist="0" MistHP="0" MistLP="0" MistVal="0" ThroughTool="0" ThroughToolHP="0" ThroughToolMP="0" ThroughToolLP="0" ThroughToolVal="0" MinQuantLubr="0" MinQuantLubrVal="0" AirActive="0" BedRinsing="0" AirThroughSpindle="0"/>
                                                                        </CC>
                                                                    </CuttingConditionsList>
                                                                    <Material Ver="1" Material="0" PercentMaterial="100" CheckPercent="0"/>
                                                                    <CutPoints>
                                                                        <CutPoint Ver="5" InchMode="0" Name="Cutting point" Id="1" OperationType="0" RadIndx="0" Description="" Hyperlink="" Color="62207" ForCut="-1" LinkToDiamCutter="-1" LockH="-1" CuttingCondition="1" OffsetNum="1" OffsetIndex="1" Radius="3" OriginNum="0" AutoOriginNum="-1" MeasureOrien="0" Flip="0" DTAxisVal="0" NosePointX="0" NosePointY="0" NosePointZ="0" CheckToolBreakage="0" CheckToolLength="0" CheckToolRadius="0" LengthTolerance="0.5" RadiusTolerance="0.1" UsedInHR="0" UsedInPart="0"/>
                                                                    </CutPoints>
                                                                </CompTool>
                                                            </Components>
                                                        </CompTool>
                                                    </Components>
                                                </CompTool>
                                            </Components>
                                        </CompTool>
                                    </Components>
                                </CompTool>
                            </Components>
                        </CompTool>
                    </Components>
                </CompTool>
            </Components>
        </CompTool>
        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="2" Name="Shanks" Type="6" FolderOf="5" Description=""/>
        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="3" Name="Adaptors and Holders" Type="6" FolderOf="2" Description="">
            <Components>
                <CompTool Ver="2" ID="28" ExtrId="121817151442" Name="SubNode 1" Type="6" FolderOf="2" Description="">
                    <Components>
                        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="29" ExtrId="121817151446" Name="SubNode 2" Type="6" FolderOf="2" Description="">
                            <Components>
                                <CompTool Ver="1" ID="30" ExtrId="121817151459" Name="1234" CatalogNum="" Description="" Hyperlink="" HasCoolantHole="0" Price="0" Mass="0" Quantity="1" MinQuantity="1" Type="2" ShapeType="2" BaseGeometry="0">
                                    <Mounting ConnectToJoint="">
                                        <MountingX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                        <MountingY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                        <MountingZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                        <MountingPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                        <MountingAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                    </Mounting>
                                    <Shape Ver="4" InchMode="0" Name="" ShapeType="2" FileName="" FromImprtDir="0">
                                        <MassCenter x="-999999999.99999" y="-999999999.99999" z="-999999999.99999"/>
                                        <Box3DB x="-1.79769313486232E+308" y="-1.79769313486232E+308" z="-1.79769313486232E+308"/>
                                        <Box3DT x="1.79769313486232E+308" y="1.79769313486232E+308" z="1.79769313486232E+308"/>
                                    </Shape>
                                    <Joints>
                                        <Joint Ver="2" InchMode="0" Name="Joint_1" ForPartMounting="0" DriveUnitType="3">
                                            <PlugIn>
                                                <PlugInX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                <PlugInY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                <PlugInZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                <PlugInPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                <PlugInAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                            </PlugIn>
                                            <Filter Ver="1"/>
                                        </Joint>
                                    </Joints>
                                </CompTool>
                                <CompTool Ver="1" ID="31" ExtrId="12181715155" Name="3456" CatalogNum="" Description="" Hyperlink="" HasCoolantHole="0" Price="0" Mass="0" Quantity="1" MinQuantity="1" Type="2" ShapeType="2" BaseGeometry="0">
                                    <Mounting ConnectToJoint="">
                                        <MountingX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                        <MountingY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                        <MountingZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                        <MountingPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                        <MountingAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                    </Mounting>
                                    <Shape Ver="4" InchMode="0" Name="" ShapeType="2" FileName="" FromImprtDir="0">
                                        <MassCenter x="-999999999.99999" y="-999999999.99999" z="-999999999.99999"/>
                                        <Box3DB x="-1.79769313486232E+308" y="-1.79769313486232E+308" z="-1.79769313486232E+308"/>
                                        <Box3DT x="1.79769313486232E+308" y="1.79769313486232E+308" z="1.79769313486232E+308"/>
                                    </Shape>
                                    <Joints>
                                        <Joint Ver="2" InchMode="0" Name="Joint_1" ForPartMounting="0" DriveUnitType="3">
                                            <PlugIn>
                                                <PlugInX x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                <PlugInY x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                                                <PlugInZ x="0" y="0" z="1"/>
                                                <PlugInPos x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                                <PlugInAngles x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                                            </PlugIn>
                                            <Filter Ver="1"/>
                                        </Joint>
                                    </Joints>
                                </CompTool>
                            </Components>
                        </CompTool>
                    </Components>
                </CompTool>
            </Components>
        </CompTool>
        <CompTool Ver="2" ID="4" Name="Fixtures" Type="6" FolderOf="4" Description=""/>
    </Components>
</ToolsItemsManager>
```

And this is the piece of code I'm using to attempt to sort this, but it is not working as I expect:

```
private static XElement Sort(
    XElement element, 
    int level, 
    string attribute, 
    int sortAttributes)
{
    XElement newElement = new XElement(element.Name,
        from child in element.Elements()
        orderby 
            (child.Ancestors().Count() > level) 
                ? ( 
                    (child.HasAttributes 
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute)
                    && child.Attribute(attribute) != null) 
                        ? child.Attribute(attribute).Value.ToString() 
                        : child.Name.ToString() 
                    ) 
                : ""  //End of the orderby clause
        select Sort(child, level, attribute, sortAttributes));
    if (element.HasAttributes)
    {
        switch (sortAttributes)
        {
            case 0: //None
                foreach (XAttribute attrib in element.Attributes())
                {
                    newElement.SetAttributeValue(attrib.Name, attrib.Value);
                }
                break;
            case 1: //Ascending
                foreach (XAttribute attrib in element.Attributes()
                                                     .OrderBy(a => a.Name.ToString()))
                {
                    newElement.SetAttributeValue(attrib.Name, attrib.Value);
                }
                break;
            case 2: //Decending
                foreach (XAttribute attrib in element.Attributes()
                                                     .OrderByDescending(
                                                         a => a.Name.ToString()))
                {
                    newElement.SetAttributeValue(attrib.Name, attrib.Value);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return newElement;
}
```

Can anyone just point me in the right direction here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have .NET classes which represent your xml model? It would be pretty trivial if so, with serialization

Comment: Also your image displays a simpler Xml structure than your code. I could give you something based on the Xml in the image, but I'm not typing out everything according to the code. Perhaps we just can't see the Mounting, Joint, Shapes etc in the image

Comment: You are correct. The image does not show additional attributes of these elements I want to sort. Honestly, I don't think I can come up with a better image because the UI of the application generating these XMLs is indeed dense.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion.

Have a pattern like this:

```
For each element in root
  Sort(element)

In Sort
  if(element has child nodes with name starting with 'CompTool')
     Call Sort on each of them
  else
     Your at the base of one node tree, and sort it.
```

Only its a little more difficult since you have a `Components` tag in there. Its unclear if you have more than one `Components` tag in each CompTool, or only one.

In either case, you're checking to see if there are child `CompTool`s of the `Components`. And calling `Sort(on each CompTool)`.